# Postgis <@> operator, what does it do?

Tags: postgresql, geolocation, postgis

I am comparing to points with <@> to get the distance between them. I was told it would return the distance in miles if the points contained latitude and longitude coordinates.

I can't seem to find the reference now, typing in search terms for related to calculating distance between to coordinates does not show anything on this operator. Typing in "<@>" into google or this site does not show any results.

The <@> operator does return something when I use it in postgres. It seems like it shows the miles, but seems way off for some comparisons.

So what does this operator do? And what is the correct way to calculate distance in miles (would actually prefer km) between to geo-coordinates?

Comment: Would you think it might be relevant to mention your Postgres and PostGIS version? Because it totally is. Just like the data types of your operands and the query you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely not using postgis, but the old [`earthdistance` extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/earthdistance.html)

> `point <@> point` float8  Gives the distance in statute miles between two points on the Earth's surface.

This uses the point type and not Geography/Geometery.

Comment: So why would say: select point(49.899754,-97.137494) <@> point(52.350009,-97.038173); yield a result of 22 miles, when in reality  it is 169 miles?

Comment: Switch x and y and try again, per the docs **points are taken as (longitude, latitude)**. `select point(-97.137494,49.899754) <@> point(-97.038173,52.350009);` Also, use dba.se not stackoverflow.

Comment: Why is eathdistance backwards?

Comment: IT's a PG thing to mirror X and Y axis.

Comment: @GregValcourt if you're content with this answer mark it as chosen.

Comment: The axis mirroring, isn't that just cartesian vs geographic coords?